# Variable length chromosome in GA

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

If I have a matrix such as the following...

```
test case | branch 1 | branch 2 | branch 3 | branch 4
-----------------------------------------------------
Test1     | x        | o        | x        | o
Test2     | o        | o        | x        | o
Test3     | x        | x        | x        | o
Test4     | x        | o        | x        | x
Test5     | x        | x        | x        | x
```

I'm trying to optimize for max branch coverage but minimum tests this could mean my GA chromosome would need to store 100+ tests or just one.

For example in this example I just need Test5 so I could have a binary chromosome of just,

```
101
```

However, I might need more...

```
101001
```

Is this the representation to use? If so what mutation and crossover operators would I need to use?

Answer (score 0):

That could work.

To do mutation, you could either include or exclude some number of tests (or go through all tests and change them from included to excluded or vice versa with a small probability).

To do cross-over, you could go through both chromosomes and, if both include a test, include it, if both exclude it, exclude it, if one includes it, either include or exclude it.

To do this efficiently, you should keep the tests sorted, so test 1 and 5 would be `001101`, not `101001`.

I'm of course assuming you can only include each test once, but, if not, this wouldn't change the approach much.

I'd only go for the binary representation if you're actually going to store it in binary though. You often use binary in chromosomes when mutation and cross-over on a binary level would make sense, but here it's very unlikely to (I mean, for example, changing test 3 (`11`) to test 7 (`111`) requires 1 bit change (fairly likely), where-as changing test 3 (`11`) to test 12 (`1100`) requires 4 bit changes (quite unlikely) - so there'd be a much stronger relationship between certain tests compared to others, which is unlikely to be representative of the actual relationships, if any, which would typically lead to bad results and/or performance), so you may as well go for a decimal representation (or whatever is a combination of small enough and easy enough to work with).

Keep in mind that this won't necessarily work for your particularly application, as tests may be interdependent, meaning if one is included, another would also need to be included. If this happens, you may want to group tests for those that all require each other, or have 3 options (e.g. 0/1/2) if one is just dependent on another. Or there could be other factors which would make the above a less than ideal approach - you just need to think through what the mutation and cross-over is actually doing and whether this makes sense for your application.